# Weblogic 10.3.1.0 is using com.bea.core.apache.commons.net_1.0.0.0_1-4-1.jar... I want to use commons-net-2.0.jar from my code

Tags: java, weblogic, classpath, weblogic-10.x

Weblogic 10.3.1.0 is using com.bea.core.apache.commons.net_1.0.0.0_1-4-1.jar... I want to use commons-net-2.0.jar from my code.

How can I force it to use the newer JAR in my code only?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I want to use commons-net-2.0.jar from my code.

WebLogic uses a **parent class loader first strategy** and you basically have two options to tweak this behavior:

- Use the [prefer-web-inf-classes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html#wp1082452) element in a `weblogic.xml` Web application deployment descriptor (that goes in WEB-INF next to the `web.xml`) ~or~
- Package your war insider an EAR and use WebLogic [Filtering classloader](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html#wp1097187) that you configure in a `weblogic-application.xml` descriptor (that goes in META-INF next to the `application.xml`)

Here is an example weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app
 xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic- web-app.xsd">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
     </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Here is an example weblogic-application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
    <application-param>
        <param-name>webapp.encoding.default</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </application-param>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

The former option is simpler but is global to the webapp. The later introduces more complexity if you're not currently using an EAR packaging but gives finer control.

#### See also

- [Understanding WebLogic Server Application Classloading](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the required JAR in \WEB-INF\lib of the WAR, \APP-INF\lib of the EAR or the \lib directory of the EAR file?

If your project is a standalone web project (with no EJBs), placing the JAR in WEB-INF\lib should be sufficient. For enterprise applications that possibly have EJB modules and Web modules bundled in a EAR file, APP-INF\lib should work, although I'm not so sure about WebLogic Server's support for the library directory (usually a \lib directory in the EAR file, but sometimes configurable via application.xml) concept brought out in Java EE 5.

**EDIT**:
In the scenario where the application server's library is loaded ahead of the one present in the application, WebLogic Server's feature of [filtered classloaders](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html#wp1098468) will aid in ensuring that the application always has the right classes loaded from its classpath, instead of the server's classpath.

Comment: Yes... I have commons-net-2.0.jar in the EAR file's lib folder and that works for other dependencies. But at runtime it is using the one from Weblogic... bea/modules/com.bea.core.apache.commons.net_1.0.0.0_1-4-1.jar

Comment: Oh ok, then it appears that the one from the server has already been loaded. I've updated my answer. Although the link is for WLS 10.3, it applies even for 10.3.1.