# Deployment Failed Spring 3.1 on Weblogic Server 10.3.4

Tags: spring, spring-security, weblogic-10.x, spring-3

I've been developing maven java spring 3.1 program and deploy it on jetty. It ran successfully on jetty. And now I need to deploy it on weblogic 10.3.4 but I always get this BeanDefinitionParserDelegate error. Is there anything (like library or class) I should add to weblogic environment to get it work?

Here are my error stack trace:

```
951  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']
ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:375) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:298) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:241) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49) [spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) [com.bea.core.weblogic.security.identity_1.1.2.1.jar:1.1.2.1]
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) [com.bea.core.weblogic.security.wls_1.0.0.0_6-1-0-0.jar:6.1.0.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.9.0.0.jar:1.9.0.0]
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.9.0.0.jar:1.9.0.0]
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.9.0.0.jar:1.9.0.0]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:69) ~[spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1114) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1104) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:90) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:458) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:353) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
... 48 common frames omitted
```

And this is my xml code in spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<beans:bean id="customAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<beans:bean id="loginService" class="com.pusilkom.artajasa.billing.service.LoginService" />

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.pusilkom.artajasa.billing.util.ArtajasaAuthenticationProvider" />
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="com.pusilkom.artajasa.billing.util.ThouShaltNoPass">
    <beans:property name="accessDeniedURL" value="/session/403/" />
</beans:bean>
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logs show that you have Spring 2.0.3 on your classpath, you need to have atleast Spring 3.0.6 to work with Spring Security 3.1.x. So try cleaning your classpath or check if the jar is being included from other projects.

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1114) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
```

Comment: Hi, Ravi. Thx for your response (and it was fast too). I've tried to fix the version in my pom file, unfortunately we already used spring-3.1.0.RELEASE and I see nothing about including spring 2.0.3 to our project. Should I include spring 3.1.0 manually to overwrite spring 2.0.3?

Comment: Oh, forgot to tell you that Yes, there is spring 2.0.3 in our dependency files, but I don't think it come from pom file since we don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the prefer-web-inf-classes element? In `WEB-INF/weblogic.xml` (next to `web.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app
 xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 
http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic- web-app.xsd">
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
 </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

See: [Weblogic 10.3.1.0 is using com.bea.core.apache.commons.net_1.0.0.0_1-4-1.jar... I want to use commons-net-2.0.jar from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376046/weblogic-10-3-1-0-is-using-com-bea-core-apache-commons-net-1-0-0-0-1-4-1-jar)