# Error processing persistent unit when deploying ear in weblogic using eclipselink

Tags: persistence, weblogic, eclipselink

I'm work on a multi module maven project and for the persistence I use eclipselink. When I deploy the ear file in weblogic I always get this error message: Failed to load webapp /yyy. Error processing persistent unit xxx of module /yyy. Error instantiating the Persistence Provider class org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl of the PersistentUnit xxx. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.
I guess it tries to use the default openjpa provider, but I have configured it to use eclipselink in the persistence.xml. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [prefer-web-inf-classes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html#wp1082452) element in your `weblogic.xml` application descriptor.
According to the documentation,

> Setting this element to True subverts the classloader delegation model so that class definitions from the Web application are loaded in preference to class definitions in higher-level classloaders. This allows a Web application to use its own version of a third-party class, which might also be part of WebLogic Server.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376046/weblogic-10-3-1-0-is-using-com-bea-core-apache-commons-net-1-0-0-0-1-4-1-jar) is a related question which might help you as well.